# Potential vs Potential Difference for a line charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, potential-energy

How would I calculate potential for an infinite line of charge a distance 'r' away from it?
What does the reference point for potential difference mean? 
I know delta v = Q/(2pi*epsilon0*L)*ln(r2/r1) for this situation. Does this delta v equal the v at a distance r1 where r2 is the reference point? Do I need to be given a potential at the reference point r2 to find the true potential?

Comment: Your delta(v) expression gives the potential difference between two points located at distances r1 and r2. If your task is to find the potential at some distance r from the wire, then you need to be given the potential voltage at some point of reference and then apply this equation to find the potential voltage at the point r.

Comment: can you give me a specific example for how i would use a given voltage with the above potential difference equation?

Comment: Your delta(v) expression only gives the potential difference between two points, so if you want absolute values for the potential a reference point is needed. If, say, you define the voltage at a point 2 meters from the wire to be at 5 volts potential, then modifying your delta(v) equation gives a voltage of v(r)=Q/(2pi*epsilon0*L)*ln(r/2)+5 at any point r. Note that this expression for v(r) satisfies the requirement I imposed that v(r=2)=5 volts. For your case, if you want to determine absolute voltage potentials then you also need some fixed point of reference for the voltage.

Comment: In order to obtain $\Phi (\rho )$, I'd solve the Laplace equation with the method of separation of variables using cylindrical coordinates. I'd seek a solution that doesn't depend on z nor theta, the azimuthal angle. I'd set the potential to be 0 at $\rho \to \infty$.